# How to check sentences with roman numerals php

Tags: php

I have a sentences for breadcrumb title like `Code01 - HISTORY LESSON II - Class A`. I need to make that sentences `HISTORY LESSON II` to become `History Lesson II`. I tried using `strtolower` function first and then `ucwords` like below

```
$data = ucwords(strtolower($lesson_name));
```

and the sentences become `History Lesson Ii`. Do you know how to check if sentences have roman numbers, and if they have, only in roman numbers not changed into strtolower ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the code as you have it... You can use then `preg_replace_callback` to match roman numerals and return them in upper case.

**Code**

```
$string = "Code01 - HISTORY LESSON II - Class A";        // Subject string
$string = ucwords(strtolower($string));                  // Set sentence to Title Case

echo preg_replace_callback(
    "/(\b[ivx]+)\b/i",                                   // Pattern to match Roman Numberals; case insensitive
    function($matches){return strtoupper($matches[1]);}, // Function to return numerals in uppercase
    $string                                              // Subject to run pattern against
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **preg_match_all** and **array_map** also.

```
$string = "Code01 - HISTORY LESSON II - Class A";
$string = ucwords(strtolower($string));
$pattern = '/\b(?:X?L?(?:X{0,3}(?:IX|IV|V|V?I{1,3})|IX|X{1,3})|XL|L)\b/i';
preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);
$upper = array_map('strtoupper',$matches[0]);

echo str_replace($matches[0],$upper,$string);
```

Output with:

```
Code01 - History Lesson II - Class A
```